# Filter columns of data in C with a txt file input

Tags: c, arrays, string, text, io

I am doing an C program assignment about giving a route to the user. At the beginning, I am given some data regarding the stop_id, location etc.

The sample data is like this

```
location_type, parent_station, stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id
0,,10000,10000,"Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd","",-32.1479054960,116.0201957650,4
0,,10001,10001,"Albany Hwy After Frys L","",-32.1449537724,116.0183152090,3
```

The information I need are  stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_lat and stop_lon. **Given that I should try  not  to use `strtok()`**, what would be the useful approach for me to filter out those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `char*` or `char[]` containing the characters in your line called `input`.

You could keep a couple pointers to the start and end of a substring that contains the desired element in the comma-separated string, and just loop over all the characters in the string.

When you have valid start and end positions, do a `memcpy()` to grab the characters of interest, and add a NUL terminator to the string you just copied:

```
#define MAX_LEN 512
#define MAX_ENTRIES 9

/* run the following for each line of input */

char* start = &input[0];
char* end = &input[0];
char entry[MAX_ENTRIES][MAX_LEN];
uint32_t entry_idx = 0;
int finished = 0; // false
do {
    end = strchr(start, ',');
    if (!end) {
        end = input + strlen(input);
        finished = 1;
    }
    memcpy(entry[entry_idx], start, end - start);
    entry[entry_idx][end - start] = '\0';
    entry_idx++;
    start = end + 1;
} while (!finished);
```

Getting the value of a field is just a matter of dereferencing the right entry index (i.e., `entry[2]` for `stop_id`, `entry[3]` for `stop_code`, etc.).

Note that what you are dereferencing is a `char[]`, so any numerical value might need conversion to an integer or floating point value, depending on what you need to export. Functions like `sscanf()` etc. can help here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the main task here is to split a string into substrings at given delimiters (`,` in this case), one could do the following.

```or-tag-here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
       return 1;

    getline(&line, &len, fp); // ignore first line
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {    
        unsigned int begin[10], leng[10];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        begin[0] = 0;
        j++;

        for (i = 0; i < read; ++i)
        {
            if (line[i] == ',')
            {
                begin[j] = i+1;
                leng[k] = i-begin[j-1];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
            else if (line[i] == '\n')
            {
                leng[k] = i-begin[j-1];
                k++;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            printf("(%.*s)\n", leng[i], &line[begin[i]]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
       free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

At first I'm reading the file line by line ignoring the first one. By iterating over every character of a line, I save the indices of the beginning and the length of every column. After that I print out every column for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you are trying to write a CSV parser. CSV is very convenient to use for data interchange, but I generaly use a dedicated library because of possible corner cases ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)):

- you can have delimiters (commas) in a quoted string
- you can have record separators (newline) in a quoted string
- you can have a quote in a quoted string (it is just doubled)

IMHO, if you want to do it *by hand* (as you say you must not use `strtok`), you should:

- read the input one char at a time with `fgetc`
- if in a quoted string:

  - gather everything that is not a quote
  - gather a quote if you get 2
  - end the quoted string when you find a quote not followed by a second one
- else:

  - pass to next field on a comma
  - ignore blank characters (spaces, tabs and `\r`)
  - return a full record (a char**) when getting a new line (`\n`) or a end of file

It will be simpler to code if you know the number of fields.

If it can help, here is an example of parser compatible with a RFC 4180 csv data file. It parses the input file and repeatedly calls a callback function with an array of C strings (null terminated char arrays) as parameter. The array itself is terminated with a null pointer. It correctly accepts quotes, delimiters and new lines in quoted fields:

```
enum retval { OK = 0, MEMALLOC, SYNTAX, UNTERM, ABORT };

int add(char **line, unsigned int index, char c, size_t *size) {
    if (index >= *size - 1) {
        char *buf = realloc(*line, *size *2);
        if (buf == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        *size *= 2;
        *line = buf;
    }
    (*line)[index] = c;
    return 0;
}

int csvparse(FILE *fd, char delim, char quote, int *linenum, int *pos,
             int (*process)(char **)) {
    enum { BEFORE, FIELD, QFIELD, AFTER} mode = BEFORE;
    int c;
    unsigned int index = 0, findex = 0;
    size_t linesize = 1024;
    size_t maxFields = 256;
    char **fields = calloc(maxFields, sizeof(char *));
    char *line = malloc(linesize);
    enum retval retval = OK;
    if (linenum != NULL) *linenum = 1;
    if (pos != NULL) *pos = 0;
    if (quote == 0) quote = '"';
    if (delim == 0) delim = ',';
    fields[0] = line;
    while ((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        if (pos != NULL) *pos += 1;
        if (mode == QFIELD) {
            if (c == quote) {
                c = fgetc(fd);
                if (c != quote) {
                    ungetc(c, fd);
                    mode = AFTER;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (add(&line, index++, c, &linesize) != 0) {
                retval = MEMALLOC;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (c == quote) {
            mode = QFIELD;
        }
        else if (c == delim) {
            if (add(&line, index++, '\0', &linesize) != 0) {
                retval = MEMALLOC;
                break;
            }
            if (findex >= maxFields - 2) {
                void * buf = realloc(fields, maxFields * 2);
                if (buf == NULL) {
                    retval = MEMALLOC;
                    break;
                }
                maxFields *= 2;
                fields = buf;
            }
            fields[++findex] = line + index;
            mode = BEFORE;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            if (add(&line, index++, '\0', &linesize) != 0) {
                retval = MEMALLOC;
                break;
            }
            if (mode == FIELD) {
                char *lastf = fields[findex];
                char *last = lastf + strlen(lastf) -1;
                while (isspace(*last) && (last > lastf)) {
                    *(last--) = '\0';
                }
            }
            fields[findex + 1] = NULL;
            if (process(fields) == -1) {
                retval = ABORT;
                break;
            }
            if (linenum != NULL) *linenum += 1;
            if (pos != NULL) *pos = 0;
            index = findex = 0;
            mode = BEFORE;
        }
        else if (((mode == AFTER) || (mode == BEFORE)) && isspace(c)) {
            ;
        }
        else {
            if (mode == BEFORE) mode = FIELD;
            else if (mode == AFTER) {
                retval = SYNTAX;
                break;
            }
            if (add(&line, index++, c, &linesize) != 0) {
                retval = MEMALLOC;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (add(&line, index++, c, &linesize) != 0) {
        retval = MEMALLOC;
    }
    if (mode == QFIELD) {
        retval = UNTERM;
    }
    if ((retval == OK) && ((mode != BEFORE) || (findex != 0))) {
        process(fields);
    }
    free(line);
    free(fields);
    return retval;
}
```